# Convert multiple json string into one string

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I want to convert my multiple json string into single string.

This is my multiple json string how can I convert it into single string .I am getting this string as a response of ajax.

```
[  
   {  
      "name1":"pizaa",
      "count1":8
   },
   {  
      "name2":"sandvich",
      "count2":8
   },
   {  
      "name3":"Burger",
      "count3":8
   },
   {  
      "name4":"TEST category",
      "count4":8
   },
   {  
      "name5":"TEST category",
      "count5":8
   },
   {  
      "name6":"TEST category",
      "count6":8
   },
   {  
      "name7":"final test",
      "count7":8
   },
   {  
      "name8":"final final test",
      "count8":8
   }
]
```

output like this:

```
   [  
   {  
      "name1":"pizaa",
      "count1":8,
      "name2":"sandvich",
      "count2":8
   }
   ]
```

Comment: not very clear. you want to join all the fields of all objects into a single object? why are you only considering the first 2 objects?

Comment: i want to join all fields. i was just showing output that  i want get to get output like this

Comment: @Cool - `count` is a property of an object. If you are going to merge the objects in one then `count` property will be overridden and hence, desired output is impossible to achieve unless and until you have same value for `count` for all the objects.

Comment: The index appended for name & count is sequencial rt like 1,2,3?

Comment: Yeah i know but how can i merge multiple json string. Igonre the string $nikhil

Comment: yeah right @sanjay kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a solution in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminur/nkj2n6x0/). Here i've used `JSON.stringify`

```js
var json = [{
  "name1": "pizaa",
  "count": 8
}, {
  "name2": "sandvich",
  "count": 8
}, {
  "name3": "Burger",
  "count": 8
}, {
  "name4": "TEST category",
  "count": 8
}, {
  "name5": "TEST category",
  "count": 8
}, {
  "name6": "TEST category",
  "count": 8
}, {
  "name7": "final test",
  "count": 8
}, {
  "name8": "final final test",
  "count": 8
}]

var finalString = '';
finalString = JSON.stringify(json);
finalString = finalString.replace(/},{/g, ",");
alert(finalString);
```

Comment: For future reference please include any code in the text of the answer itself as links to outside sources can and do go dead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to post a solution to your question. Have a look:

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "name1":"pizaa",
      "count1":8
   },
   {  
      "name2":"sandvich",
      "count2":8
   },
   {  
      "name3":"Burger",
      "count3":8
   },
   {  
      "name4":"TEST category",
      "count4":8
   },
   {  
      "name5":"TEST category",
      "count5":8
   },
   {  
      "name6":"TEST category",
      "count6":8
   },
   {  
      "name7":"final test",
      "count7":8
   },
   {  
      "name8":"final final test",
      "count8":8
   }
];

var result = [];
var reduced = {};
data.map(function(a) {
  for(var p in a) {
    reduced[p] = a[p];
  }
});
result[0] = reduced;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I updated my code slightly. You might want to have another look. 

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jsonData = [{"name1":"pizaa","count1":8},{"name2":"sandvich","count2":8},{"name3":"Burger","count3":8},{"name4":"TEST category","count4":8},{"name5":"TEST category","count5":8},{"name6":"TEST category","count6":8},{"name7":"final test","count7":8},{"name8":"final final test","count8":8}];
var modJson = {};
$.each(jsonData, function(index, val) {
  modJson['name'+(index+1)] = val['name'+(index+1)];
  modJson['count'+(index+1)] = val['count'+(index+1)];
});
console.log(modJson);
```